# Would this question be on-topic here? Might it be likely to receive an answer?

Tags: discussion, topicality

I'm writing a program and need a way to identify and enumerate the number of possible distinct crystallographic domains when depositing one 2D lattice on top of another.

I've posed this as a question in Math SE: [Number of possible rotational domains of one 2D lattice on top of another?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3566248/284619) but possibly because I lack the proper "math words" it might not be receiving views by the users who can answer it. I'm sure it's a solved problem.

**Questions:**

1. Would this question be on-topic here if suitably rewritten for this site?
2. If so, might it be likely to receive an answer?

---

Snippet from the linked question:

> Square and hexagonal lattices shown at 0, 30 and 60 degrees:
>
> [image: square and hexagonal lattices shown at 0, 30 and 60 degrees]
>
> Square and hexagonal lattices shown at +/-10 degrees:
>
> [image: square and hexagonal lattices shown at +/-10 degrees]

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by *absolute angle*.

Comment: @nicoguaro Thanks, I probably need to work on that. I think you're referring to "a given angle who's absolute value is $\theta$" in the linked question. In the description of the problem above that I say "If I ask for an offset of 10 degrees then there are two ways (+/- 10°)." You are right there are more clearer ways to say what I'm trying to describe, I'll think about it. I mention crystallographic domains in the question, and those are regions that are geometrically distinct but have the same energy.

Comment: For two hexagonal lattices of the lowest symmetry group the +10 and -10 degree orientations would have the same energy. That's the kind of thing I'm getting at, but I'm still having trouble expressing this. I appreciate the input.

Comment: It seems that the problem you describe is something that can be either computed exactly or estimated numerically.  We don’t get very many questions regarding computational abstract algebra/group theory so it may not get the attention you seek as posed.  Try to reframe it as a computational geometry question if possible.  You may also want to break it into several smaller questions that build to answer your question.  Ex. How can i detect rotational symmetry on a discrete lattice numerically?

Comment: @Paul I see what you mean, thanks!